# 100-bit binary ripple carry adde

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a 100-ripple carry adder. Fist I design a full adder. Then I need to connect 100 full adders.
I am getting errors:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at top_module.v(11) near text:
>   "instance1";  expecting "<=", or "=", or "+=", or "-=", or "*=", or
>   "/=", or "%=", or "&=", or "|=", or "^=", or "<<=", or ">>=", or
>   "<<<=", or ">>>=", or "++", or "--". Check for and fix any syntax
>   errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The
>   Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific
>   details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at
>   https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html
>   and search for this specific error message number. File:
>   /var/www/verilog/work/vlg7ccmQf_dir/top_module.v Line: 11

```
module top_module( 
input [99:0] a, b,
input cin,
output [99:0] cout,
output [99:0] sum );

assign {cout[0],sum[0]}=a[0]+b[0]+cin;
always@ (*)
    begin
        for (int i=1; i<$bits(a);i++)
                full_adder instance1(
                    .a_1(a[i]),
                    .b_1(b[i]),
                    .cin_1(cout[i-1]),
                    .cout_1(cout[i]),
                    .sum_1(sum[i])
                );

   end
endmodule
module full_adder(
    input a_1, b_1,
    input cin_1,
    output cout_1,
    output sum_1
);
    assign {cout_1,sum_1}=cin_1+a_1+b_1;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

well, you cannot instantiate a module inside of an always block. Try a generate block instead:

```
...
assign {cout[0],sum[0]}=a[0]+b[0]+cin;

genvar i;

for ( i=1; i<$bits(a);i=i+1)
  full_adder instance1(
    .a_1(a[i]),
    .b_1(b[i]),
    .cin_1(cout[i-1]),
    .cout_1(cout[i]),
    .sum_1(sum[i])
  );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a module inside of a procedural block. Try to use generate block instead:

The final code should be like this:

```
module top_module( 
  input [99:0] a, b,
  input cin,
  output [99:0] cout,
  output [99:0] sum
);
  assign {cout[0],sum[0]}=a[0]+b[0]+cin;
  genvar i;
  generate 
    for ( i = 1; i < $size(a); i++ ) begin : gen
      full_adder instance1(
        .a_1(a[i]),
        .b_1(b[i]),
        .cin_1(cout[i-1]),
        .cout_1(cout[i]),
        .sum_1(sum[i])
      );
    end : gen
  endgenerate
endmodule


module full_adder(
  input a_1, b_1,
  input cin_1,
  output cout_1,
  output sum_1
);
  assign {cout_1,sum_1}=cin_1+a_1+b_1;
endmodule
```

Please pay attention to the **for-label ":gen"**, it is necessary and the code will not work without it.